# Model loss remains unchaged

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, learning-rate

I would like to understand what could be responsible for this model loss behaviour. Training a CNN network, with 6 hidden-layers, the loss shoots up from around 1.8 to above 12 after the first epoch and remains constant for the remaining 99 epochs.

```
724504/724504 [==============================] - 358s 494us/step - loss: 1.8143 - acc: 0.7557 - val_loss: 16.1181 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/100
724504/724504 [==============================] - 355s 490us/step - loss: 12.0886 - acc: 0.2500 - val_loss: 16.1181 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/100
724504/724504 [==============================] - 354s 489us/step - loss: 12.0886 - acc: 0.2500 - val_loss: 16.1181 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 4/100
724504/724504 [==============================] - 348s 481us/step - loss: 12.0886 - acc: 0.2500 - val_loss: 16.1181 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 5/100
724504/724504 [==============================] - 355s 490us/step - loss: 12.0886 - acc: 0.2500 - val_loss: 16.1181 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
```

I cannot believe this got to do with the dataset I work with, because I tried this with a different, publicly available dataset, the performance is exactly the same (in fact exact figures for loss/accuracy).

I also tested this with a somehow show network having 2 hidden-layers, see the performance below:

```
724504/724504 [==============================] - 41s 56us/step - loss: 0.4974 - acc: 0.8236 - val_loss: 15.5007 - val_acc: 0.0330
Epoch 2/100
724504/724504 [==============================] - 40s 56us/step - loss: 0.5204 - acc: 0.8408 - val_loss: 15.5543 - val_acc: 0.0330
Epoch 3/100
724504/724504 [==============================] - 41s 56us/step - loss: 0.6646 - acc: 0.8439 - val_loss: 15.3904 - val_acc: 0.0330
Epoch 4/100
724504/724504 [==============================] - 41s 57us/step - loss: 8.8982 - acc: 0.4342 - val_loss: 15.5867 - val_acc: 0.0330
Epoch 5/100
724504/724504 [==============================] - 41s 57us/step - loss: 0.5627 - acc: 0.8444 - val_loss: 15.5449 - val_acc: 0.0330
```

Can someone points the probable cause of this behaviour? What parameter / configuration needs be adjusted?

**EDIT**

Model creation

```
model = Sequential()
activ = 'relu'
model.add(Conv2D(32, (1, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', activation=activ, input_shape=(1, n_points, 4)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (1, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', activation=activ))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(1, 2)))
#model.add(Dropout(.5))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (1, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', activation=activ))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (1, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', activation=activ))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(1, 2)))
#model.add(Dropout(.5))

model.add(Conv2D(128, (1, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', activation=activ))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (1, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', activation=activ))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(1, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(.5))


model.add(Flatten())
A = model.output_shape
model.add(Dense(int(A[1] * 1/4.), activation=activ))
model.add(Dropout(.5))

model.add(Dense(NoClass, activation='softmax'))

optimizer = Adam(lr=0.0001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_reample, Y_resample, epochs=100, batch_size=64, shuffle=False,
                           validation_data=(Test_X, Test_Y))
```

Changing the learning rate to `lr=0.0001` here's the result after `100 epochs`.

```
72090/72090 [==============================] - 29s 397us/step - loss: 0.5040 - acc: 0.8347 - val_loss: 4.3529 - val_acc: 0.2072
Epoch 99/100
72090/72090 [==============================] - 28s 395us/step - loss: 0.4958 - acc: 0.8382 - val_loss: 6.3422 - val_acc: 0.1806
Epoch 100/100
72090/72090 [==============================] - 28s 393us/step - loss: 0.5084 - acc: 0.8342 - val_loss: 4.3781 - val_acc: 0.1925
the optimal epoch size: 97, the value of high accuracy 0.20716827656581954
```

EDIT 2

Apparently, SMOTE isn't good for sampling all but majority class in a multiclassification, see below the trian/test plot:
[image]

Comment: Your learning rate is probably too high

Comment: Optimizer settings: `optimizer = Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)`

Comment: Mmm that looks ok, did you try other optimizers such as SGD? Also it would help if you include the model and compile statements

Comment: Question edited to include model compile statement.

Comment: So changing the learning rate seemed to be the problem.

Comment: Ah, I can confirm this is caused by applying the SMOTE technique. The dataset is highly imbalanced, so I used the SMOTE technique, resampling all but the majority class. Here comes the effect.

Answer (score -1):

Can you please try using [BatchNormalization](https://keras.io/layers/normalization/) also, place just after your pooling layers. it is good to include it

Comment: I understand the problem is as a result of sampling technique. This is a multi-classification (5-classes) problem, and the data set is highly imbalanced. So I applied the SMOTE technique sampling all but `not majority` making each class having 20% instances of train set. But end up with such a problem

Comment: In case of highly imbalance dataset accuracy is not good metric, please try other metric like Precision, Recall, F1 score etc

Comment: Applying SMOTE is not good as you describe above because it makes data points of majority class equal to minority class in your 5 class multi-class data